# Splicing Stuff With Js

Tags: javascript, array-splice

Ok, I'm making an evolution simulator and they need to get food to survive. Blah blah blah. But this splice isn't working and I don't know how to fix it

The code:

```
function track(blob, ob) {
    for (let i = 0; i < ob.length; i++) {
        const dist = Math.hypot(
            blob.x - ob[i].x, 
            blob.y - ob[i].y
        )

        if (dist - 20 - blob.size < 1) {
            blob.food++
            ob.splice(ob[i], 1)
        } else {
            const angle = Math.atan2(
                ob[i].x - blob.y,
                ob[i].y - blob.x
            )
            const velocity = {
                x: Math.cos(angle) / 2,
                y: Math.sin(angle) / 2
            }
            blob.velocity = velocity
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it throw an error, or does it not work as intended?

Comment: 1. What is `ob`? 2. What do you expect to happen? 3. What happens instead?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The way `.splice()` works is you specify the starting index, the number of items to delete, and a list of items to insert at that index.

```js
var array = [3, 4, 5, 6];
array.splice(1, 1);
console.log(array); //[3, 5, 6]
array.splice(2, 0, 7);
console.log(array); //[3, 5, 7, 6]
array.splice(0, 2, 1, 8);
console.log(array); //[1, 8, 5, 7, 6]
```

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)